# Does writing a tag over multiple lines in HTML adds whitespace/return characters in the DOM?

Tags: html, css

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKwQoe
I have the following code:

```css
.required:after {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  content: "*";
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.myDiv {
  background-color: tan;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <ul>
    <li class="required">One</li>
    <li class="required">Two</li>
    <li class="required">Three</li>
    <li class="required">Four</li>
    <li class="required">
      Five turns out to be long
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With that last `li` tag, my "required" asterisk gets punted down one line. However, if I write that same exact tag one line like this:

`<li class="required">Five turns out to be long</li>`

...the asterisk stays on the same line. It seems to be that the first version of the code generates this HTML:

```
<li class="required">
  "
  Five turns out to be long
  "
  ::after
</li>
```

...and the other example generates this:

```
<li class="required">
  "Five turns out to be long"
  ::after
</li>
```

I don't understand exactly what's going on here and I lack the language to explain to my coworkers why I need to change some of their tags to be on only one line. What exactly is this behavior, and is it documented anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: better avoid using absolute without explicitely specifying the position or you will have headaches dealing with the *static position* (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) ... simply add `top:0;left:100%` in your case

Comment: do you need `Five turns out to be long` or `five` to be displayed but with `turns out to be long`

Comment: Hard to explain. here. It shouldn't be on the next line and isn't in Firefox and Chrome Canary. So you're basically coding around a Chrome bug that's going away soon.